# Truncating text with image

Tags: html, css, image, truncate

I was trying to truncate the text based on this [link](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iBtep)

Now I am using class as follows

```
.line-clamp {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

It works fine with just text. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5gg6y4x/2/)

The issue is I also want to include an image with this truncated text so I was trying to [include image inside div](https://jsfiddle.net/w5gg6y4x/5/). Even putting image [outside the div](https://jsfiddle.net/w5gg6y4x/4/) shows image below the text. I am not getting the proper output. How can I put image such a way that I can see that image at the end of text.

Comment: I fail to understand what you're trying to achieve, which should be the proper output?

Comment: @ArnauFernández I wamt to put image at the end of the truncated text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the box shorter and float it

```css
.line-clamp {
  margin: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  width:90%; float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-clamp">
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
 </div>
 <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-help-circled-128.png" width="20px" alt="" class="panel-icon" title="image">
```

Comment: This is as simple as such. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If i reduce the width of DIV it goes down the line. Is there anything like adjusting width?

Comment: Like here it is given width as 90%. but sometime. So can we adjust that as well ?

Comment: You could possibly adjust to -width of image plus margin